# Rspec uninitialized constant ActiveRecord(NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I followed codeschool tutorial, but I encountered some troubles.

Here is **zombie_spec.rb**

```
#spec/model/zombie_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'zombie'


describe Zombie do
it 'is invalid without a name' do
    zombie = Zombie.new 
    zombie.should_not be_valid
    end     
end
```

**zombie.rb**

```
#spec/zombie.rb
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base 
    validates :name, presence: true
    ...
end
```

After I typed `rspec spec/models/zombie_spec.rb`, it throw `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)`

I've put this project on [github](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/Rspec_pra/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tutorial might be trying to transition from using RSpec on a plain Ruby object to using the `rspec-rails` gem on an ActiveRecord object. For the examples that use `rspec-rails`, you should have a model in the file `app/models/zombie.rb`. This is what the spec in `spec/models/zombie_spec.rb` will look for. Also, your specs will need to require `rails_helper` rather than `spec_helper`.

```
# app/models/zombie.rb
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true

  def hungry?
    true
  end
end

# spec/models/zombie_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe Zombie do
  it 'is invalid without a name' do
    zombie = Zombie.new
    zombie.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: I misunderstand its meaning, thanks. I've modified and gotten the right expectation.

Answer (score 1):

`Zombie` is extending `ActiveRecord::Base` but your code can't find `ActiveRecord`.

To fix that you can `require 'activerecord'` within `zombie.rb`.  Depending on whether or not it's installed, you may need to also `gem install activerecord` from your command line or, alternatively, add `gem 'activerecord'` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

Comment: It's really weird, I try two ways you mention, but it still throw the same error.
If I add `require 'activerecord'` in `zombie.rb`, it throw `require': cannot load such file -- activerecord (LoadError)`. I add this projoct on github and have post it on question.

Comment: What do you see if you type `gem install activerecord --no-ri` from your terminal?

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems I put `zombie.rb` in wrong folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example that worked well for me:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Auction, :type => :model do
  it "is valid with valid attributes"
  it "is not valid without a title"
  it "is not valid without a description"
  it "is not valid without a start_date"
  it "is not valid without a end_date"
end
```

I am new to ruby, so I am not 100% sure why it needs this ":type" attribute, but it fixed my problem.

([Source](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-test-rails-models-with-rspec))